# Migration doesn't work in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, mysql, database, migration

I'm trying to update the database with migration using Rider JetBrains, but when I try to "add migration" it gives me an error in the console. I believe this error is happening because my XML is causing this error because in case I don't change it to use my database connection string, the "add migration" works successfully (my database is MySQL).

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add Server="127.0.0.1" Port="3306" Database="smartparking" Uid="root" 
      Pwd="1234567"></add>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

[My server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyF8A.png)

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYkW3.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a jetbrains plugin made for handling migrations

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17026--net-ef-migration-facilitator/

Also or :

**Adding package references**

The first thing to do would be adding package references. There are a few packages we’ll be needing, the first four are typically already installed when working with Entity Framework Core:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore – the Entity Framework Core framework
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer – the SQL Server database
  driver (other databases are supported as well)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design – the Entity Framework Core
  design tooling
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design – SQL Server-specific
  tooling
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet – the cross-platform
  command line tools we are interested in

this link is helpful for you :

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/

**EDIT :**

The sample of connection string :

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Comment: Ok, I already have these packages installed, but it still doesn't work. Can you tell me if my connection string is correct?

Comment: @guirms I am not sure but I think you must use User Id and Password  , instead uid and pwd . this link maybe help you :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/DB_Tutorial_Connecting_to_MS_SQL_server.html#connect-by-using-windows-domain-authentication-macos-and-linux
or this link :
https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/03/05/working-databases-jetbrains-rider/

Comment: @guirms I put sample connectionstring in post answer , see it

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try it when i go home

Comment: I try this connection string but it doesnt work again